# Может кто-нибудь объяснить зачем нужен AMQP (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: rabbitmq

> Advanced Message Queuing Protocol - открытый протокол для передачи сообщений между компонентами системы

Разве приложения не могут обмениваться сообщениями через `HTTP`?

Comment: Прикол в том, что если приложение сломается, то другие приложения уже не смогут с ними обмениваться сообщениями и сломаются нахрен тоже. В то время как RabbitMQ положит сообщение в очередь, дождётся, пока сломанное приложение починится, и отдаст ему сообщение из очереди — будет некоторая задержка на время поломки, но ничего не сломается полностью. Это прекрасно работает с задачами, которые могут немного подождать, вроде отправки почты или конвертирования загруженного видео подобно ютубу

Comment: Кроме того, RabbitMQ может выполнять распределение нагрузки — несколько копий одного приложения могут быть запущены на разных компьютерах, а RabbitMQ случайным образом выберет, кому из них отправить сообщение, и таким образом равномерно размажет нагрузку по компам

Answer (score 2):

Самые основные различия между HTTP и AMQP это:

- HTTP - синхронный
- AMQP - асинхронный
- HTTP - одно сообщение только одному получателю
- AMQP - одно сообщение одному или нескольким получателям

Всё зависит от того как вы разрабатываете свою систему, в разных случаях будут проявляться достоинства или недостатки каждого из протоколов.

AMQP специализированный протокол и как следствие очень быстрый с минимальными накладными расходами, поддерживающий огромное количество сообщений в единицу времени (~150к сообщений в секунду для одного брокера). Так же он позволяет скрыть информацию от клиентов кто и как обрабатывает посылаемые клиентом сообщения. Клиенту достаточно знать только адрес брокера и эксчейндж, для того, чтобы отправлять сообщения. Обработчик сообщений может меняться, как и алгоритм обработки, но это будет скрыто от клиента. Это позволяет сильнее изолировать разных клиентов друг от друга.

*Одно сообщение может быть принято несколькими клиентами.*
В реализации распределения сообщений “Routes” могут быть указаны таким образом, что в зависимости от сообщения оно попадает в несколько очередей сразу, как следствие одно сообщение приходит нескольким потребителям.

*Несколько клиентов могут быть подписаны на одну очередь.*
Допустим у вас есть множество заданий по конвертированию видео. Это достаточно затратная операция вы можете создать несколько клиентов конвертеров, которые будут брать сообщения из одной и той же очереди, каждый раз когда справляются с заданием. Получается автоматическое распределение нагрузки.

Если у вас одно приложение “строчит” кучу сообщений, в формате “послал и забыл”, а клиенты по долгу обрабатывают их - стоит присмотреться к AMQP, если же у вас приложения которые периодически посылают запросы, ответы на которые являются критичными для продолжения их работы, стоит оставаться на HTTP.

В любом случае при проектировании вашей системы лучше изолировать транспортный уровень абстракцией, чтобы в случае чего с меньшей болью перейти обратно на HTTP или AMQP.